# How to allow user to toggle between color themes in a Django

Tags: python, css, django, web, django-views

So I'm working on a Django website and want visitors to the site to click the theme they want. I was able to do it with pure Html/css and Javascipt but now that im moving everything in Django it's not working. I think maybe its my path set up. Fisrt the code in my index.html

```
<h5 style="text-align: center;line-height: 0;">Personalize Theme</h5>

                {% load static %}
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../static/pythonicThinking/script.js"></script>
                <div id="theme-options-wrapper">
                    <div data-mode="light" id="light-mode" class="theme-dot" ></div>
                    <div data-mode="blue" id="blue-mode" class="theme-dot"></div>
                    <div data-mode="green" id="green-mode" class="theme-dot"></div>
                    <div data-mode="purple" id="purple-mode" class="theme-dot"></div>
                </div>

                <p id="settings-note">*Theme settings will be saved for<br>your next visit</p>
            </div>
```

the javacript file

```
console.log('Its working')

let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme')

if(theme == null){
setTheme('light')
}else{
setTheme(theme)
}

let themeDots = document.getElementsByClassName('theme-dot')


for (var i=0; themeDots.length > i; i++){
themeDots[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let mode = this.dataset.mode
    console.log('Option clicked:', mode)
    setTheme(mode)
})
}

function setTheme(mode){
if(mode == 'light'){
    document.getElementById('theme-style').href = 'default.css'
}

if(mode == 'blue'){
    document.getElementById('theme-style').href = 'blue.css'
}

if(mode == 'green'){
    document.getElementById('theme-style').href = 'green.css'
}

if(mode == 'purple'){
    document.getElementById('theme-style').href = 'purple.css'
}

localStorage.setItem('theme', mode)
}
```

the setting.py file

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

the urls.py file
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('pythonicthinking/', include('pythonicthinking.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += [
path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='pythonicthinking/', permanent=True)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the views.py file
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def home(request):
return render(request, 'pythonicthinking/index.html')
```

My defualt css is working but when I try to click the buttons to change I get this error

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/pythonicthinking/purple.css' because its 
MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is 
enabled
```

Comment: Show the code(template) that importing the static CSS file.

Comment: and the correct method to load the static js is `src="{% static 'pythonicThinking/script.js' %}"`

Comment: Maybe thats where I'm messing up do you mean show the entire index.html page that where I thought I was importing to and whenever I try to load it that way src="{% static 'pythonicThinking/script.js' %}" I get unresovled Template reference

Comment: Share those errors

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.

1st: The static file url is invalid. You must see 404 in the console.
2. It is recommended to render a specific theme instead of applying it in the client side. This can be done using the session cookie.

3. Create Customized stylessheets and render them on the server depending upon the theme